# Library/API for development of SNMP manager

Tags: snmp

I'm new to SNMP. I have to develop a manager. I've been searching on how to program for a manager. I've come across WinSNMP, SNMP++ and Net-SNMP. The plus point for Net-SNMP is that it can translate the trap content from the MIB (it can parse the MIB). But would Net-SNMP be a good choice of library for developing a manager? I was wondering if it would be a good idea to use snmptrapd as a basis to develop a manager. At the moment I'm focusing on receiving traps but eventually I'll have to program for the others too (Get, Set, ...).

What is the general outline on how to program for a manager? I have been reading on SNMP for weeks but still haven't got a clear understanding of how to go about doing it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Quick google search yields [snmp4j](http://www.snmp4j.org/) and [agentpp](http://www.agentpp.com/agen/agen.html), and both seem to have docs that can get you started

Answer (score 4):

Which toolkit you want will greatly depend on your final-end-goals and preferred language (eg, C vs C++).  Make sure you get one with SNMPv3 support, which the native windows library doesn't have (but mg-soft and snmp research's implementation does).  You'll likely have to pay money, eventually, if you want SNMPv3 support on windows using the winsnmp APIs.

Net-SNMP and SNMP++ are both well respected open libraries.  Net-SNMP has pretty much cornered the market in terms of deployment and comes pre-installed or easily available on every OS except windows (where it also works fine, but MS just doesn't package it for you).

If you want to receive traps, Net-SNMP's snmptrapd is certainly an easy place to start and offers some very simply ways to get started through extensible commands (see the snmptrapd.conf man page to help you get started) or via C (see the apps/snmptrapd*.c files for some example C-registrations).

To get started with Net-SNMP and programming outgoing management operations, you should start with the [tutorials](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials#Coding_Tutorials) about writing management applications.  If your management application is ever going to talk to multiple hosts at once, make sure you get a toolkit that does asynchronous support (see the second item in the above link).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The thing that I'm working on is to add the capability of being an SNMP manager to a SCADA (supervisory control and data acquisition) software. The manager must be able to do real time monitoring of an unlimited number of monitoring points. The software is in C++ but using C is ok too. Would Net-SNMP be suitable for this purpose? And I've read that SNMPv3 in Net-SNMP is not multi-thread safe. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: You're right it is not thread safe to have it in different threads, but you can put all the snmp things in its own thread.  The right way to do lots of requests with one thread is with the async part.

Comment: @rocket, if you do want better performance, a non-thread-safe library is usually preferred. Of course, that requires you to be a better programmer who fully understands how to write multithreading applications.

Comment: You generally don't need the overhead of threads if you can do asynchronous work instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is also JDMK 5.1 API from Sun microsyatem, it is very easy to develop the SNMP Agent as well Manager.